# GAE, Log lines throw nullpointer exception in unit tests

Tags: google-app-engine, junit

My log lines throw nullpointer exception when I run unit tests. I get no errors when I run it on local server or upload to appengine. Have I forgotten to include a test library somewhere?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.log(GenericServlet.java:254)
    at se.stuff.servlet.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:14)
    at se.stuff.MyServletTest.test(MyServletTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

My servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    // Do stuff...
    log("log stuff");
}
```

}

My test:

```
public class MyServletTest {    
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        MyServlet s = new MyServlet();
        s.doGet(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nulls in the test call `s.doGet(null, null)` cause the NullPointerException.  The servlet is probably fine, but the test does not make sense.  I suggest scrapping that test and first adding some content into doGet, then use [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) to test your servlet from the outside.

Comment: No, MyServlet doesn't use the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse parameters. It's just log("log stuff"); I didn't want to use mocks to clutter the example.